# I don't understand the use of will in this sentence

Tags: future-tense

She has been chosen and she is going to / will /is spending (spend) the next 8 months working on a school project

I choose **going to** as it is a personnal plan  and should have been decided before she was chosen and the beginning is imminent .  I thought is spending can fit but the solution was will.  Why ?

[http://olmo.pntic.mec.es/~renciso/ejercicios_1/tiempos%20verbales_gapfilling_1.htm](http://olmo.pntic.mec.es/%7Erenciso/ejercicios_1/tiempos%20verbales_gapfilling_1.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very hard for a test writer to produce a question to test between "will" and "going to", because in almost all situations, both are possible and have at most nuanced differenes in meaning.

We sometimes learn that "going to" is often used in situation of "intention" or "plans".  But in the example, it isn't her "plan" but a consequence of somebody else choosing her. This isn't her "plan", it is somebody else's.  So they want the answer "will spend".  And many native speakers would use "will spend" in this context.

But "going to" can be use in this context too.

So both answers are correct natural English.  (But if you teacher has spent the lesson telling you that "going to" is used for the speaker's plans, then don't expect to get high marks if you ignore their teaching, even if it isn't really correct)

Comment: +1 this is the right answer imo. (To add an explanation for why "is" is wrong, it is because "is" implies something is presently happening, which would mean "being chosen" and "spending the next 8 months working on a school project" are happening simultaneously, or at least that the last part is occurring in the present, which isn't the case.)

Comment: but is going to imply that it is not now but in a very recent future

Comment: No.  "Going to" means it will occur in the future.  I can say  "In 5 billion years, the sun is going to explode" and be grammatically correct.

Comment: I’ll be 17 in three months time. Then I--------------------------------------------(learn) to drive   in the same test there was this sentence i answered am going to  learn and the answer was will , here it is a personnal plan decided before so why will